# Bug on unconstrained Strings

Tags: alloy

Alloy appears to have a bug when relations include unconstrained Strings. No instance is found for the following:

```
sig foo{
    bar: String,
    yak: Int
}
pred show[]{one f:foo | f.yak=0}
run show for 1
```

If we change this to `bar: Int`, Alloy finds an instance with an arbitrary value.

Answer (score 1):

This "known for ages" bug has thankfully a workaround.
For things to work, you need to "implicitly declare" some string values by using them in a fact or a predicate.

As an example, the following signature fact will allow bar to take its value in {"a","b","c"} :

```
sig foo{
   bar: String,
   yak: Int
}{
   bar in "a"+"b"+"c"
}
```

You can also define a pool of string to be used instance wide as follows:

```
fact stringPool{
   none!= "a"+"b"+"c"+"d"+"e"
}
```

See:

[Provide Alloy with a "pool" of custom Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397887/provide-alloy-with-a-pool-of-custom-strings)

[Problem in generation of world in predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189198/problem-in-generation-of-world-in-predicate/53435440#53435440)

[How to use String in Alloy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928860/how-to-use-string-in-alloy/26946765#26946765)

and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the bug report. Can you file an [issue](https://github.com/AlloyTools/org.alloytools.alloy/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)?

BTW, strings are not well supported in Alloy. In general it's best to avoid any concrete types unless you really need them, and do everything with abstract ones. Most uses of integers aren't necessary either.